# how to add different random start and end dates in sql on per row basis where end date is larger than start date

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am very new to SQl queries. I am trying to build a database where I need to populate start and end dates for about 500 records in most of the tables. I have tried the obvious methods to populate as below. But the end dates seem to be earlier than the start date with my method. And also i want the difference between start and end dates to be around 90 days. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

My current query is:

```
UPDATE doctor
SET Beg_Date = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 4380), '01-01-2000')

UPDATE doctor
SET End_Date = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 4380), '01-01-2000')
```

Comment: `UPDATE doctor
SET End_Date = DATEADD(DAY, 88 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5), Beg_Date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `Beg_Date` as an anchor for your second date instead of computing the second date fully randomly.

```
UPDATE doctor
SET End_Date = DATEADD(DAY, 85 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 11), Beg_Date)
```

Comment: This works!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot for the code :D i spent quite an amount of time figuring this out.